# DFS Traversal for graph

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I am trying to implement DFS for graph but I keep getting the error , "Primary Expression missing before adj" in the main() . I am passing a list named adj to a function . Can someone find out the error ?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
    using namespace std;
    void dfs(int x,bool *visited,list<int>adj)
    {
        visited[x]=true;
        cout<<x<<" ";
        list<int>::iterator j;
        for(j=adj[x].begin();j!=adj[x].end();++j)
        {
            if(!visited[*j])
                dfs(*j,visited,list<int>adj);
        }

    }
    int main()
    {
        int V,u,v,i,n,x;//no of vertex;
        cin>>V;
        list<int>adj[V];
        bool visited[V];
        cin>>n;//no of vertex having out neighbours or connected 
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>u>>v;
            adj[u].push_back(v);//adding edges to the list
        }
        cin>>x; //Node from which traversing is to be started
        for(i=0;i<V;i++)
            visited[V]=false;
        dfs(x,visited,list<int>adj);

    }
```

Comment: As a side note: don't include the `<bits/stdc++.h>` header and don't use the `using namespace std;` statement.

Comment: Those are not causing any errors believe me .

Comment: `list<int>adj` as an argument simply isn't valid syntax. I don't know where you picked it up from, but it's simple to verify how to call a function.

Comment: @VishalKumar on my system, there is no `<bits/stdc++.h>`, believe me

Comment: @chris could you suggest me the correct way of passing a stl list ?

Comment: Lists are not special. It doesn't matter what type an argument is, it's always going to be passed like `foo(arg)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using some other container than list. As List containers are implemented as doubly-linked lists.

- The main drawback of lists and forward_lists compared to these other sequence containers is that they lack direct access to the elements of their position; For example, to access the sixth element in a list, one has to iterate from a known position (like the beginning or the end) to that position, which takes linear time in the distance between these. (what you are trying to do in -`for(j=adj[x].begin();j!=adj[x].end();++j)`)
- They also consume some extra memory to keep the linking information
  associated with each element (which may be an important factor for large lists of small-sized elements).
- Better use vector if you want direct access to the elements.
- Another thing I would like to point out is `dfs(x,visited,list<int>adj);` - we never define arguments in the function call.

Comment: Thank You for taking your time to answer. Yes I am well aware about the last point .The whole point of me asking this question was to ask , how to pass a list container to a function .
Ok i will try to use some other container.